# customization in react auth0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I am using `@auth0/auth0-react` library to handle authentication process. For an unauthorized user, it will redirect to back to initial screen ("/") route with this query params. `?error=unauthorized...` Then again if I am trying to execute the login it will stay on the same page. Maybe I need to find a way to clear the previous auth0 state.

```
const { loginWithRedirect, logout} = useAuth0();
const loginWithAuth0 = () => {
    logout({}); // clear previous auth 0 state
    loginWithRedirect({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/dashboard"
    });
};
```

Above is my attempt. Using `logout({})` I am trying to clear the previous auth0 state and going forward which doesn't happen. For an authorized user there's no issues. So what I need is to handle the unauthorized user behaviour. Currently it will not redirect to the dashboard which is correct for unauthorized. But what I need is to clear the previous auth0 state and redirect to the next attempt. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the `isAuthenticated` prop off of the object returned by the `useAuth0()` hook:

```
const { loginWithRedirect, logout, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

if (!isAuthenticated) {
  logout({}); // (not certain this is necessary)
  // redirect with whatever router your framework might include
}
```

Also consider the [`withAuthenticationRequired` function](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-react/modules.html#withAuthenticationRequired) which is exported from the same `@auth0/auth0-react` package, and allows you to protect a route/component and configure a redirect for unauthenticated users at the same time:

> When you wrap your components in this Higher Order Component and an anonymous user visits your component they will be redirected to the login page and returned to the page they we're redirected from after login.

Comment: I tried but no luck.